# Css background size 100% detecting height to change negative absolute position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have block 17% of window width for response. This block has :after with image as background. :after has absolute negative position with value of image height and height of image - so it fixed for ex. 82px.

I set background-size 100% and when i resize browser block 17% changes width also background changes, but absolute negative position and :after height don't changes.

image 81 x 320

Question: how to get height of background image that resizes to width of block and set changing height to absolute negative position?

```css
.side {
  width: 17%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.side:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 82px;
  left: 0;
  top: -82px;
  background: url(/img/left-bar-blue-01.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="side">

</div>
```

Comment: Post your code if you can please.

Comment: cant set image to background from my site

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want the `:after`-Element to be always on the same relative position – is this right? 
If so, you should take a look at this [article about Centering Percentage Width/Height Elements](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/).

In the past using a negative `margin` or `top` was a common approach. Now you could/should do something like this:

`.side:before {
  /* other CSS properties */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}`

This depends on your special case, which I honestly don't totally understand.